# In a line containing multiple fields, create a new line for each field, and remove that field from the old line

Tags: shell-script, awk, gawk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
elephant
kangaroo, snake, zebra
baboon
parrot, eagle, owl
...
...
```

I want to change this list so that each line has only one element in it

```
elephant
kangaroo
snake
zebra
baboon
parrot 
eagle
owl
...
...
```

Is there any way to do this in awk?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do in a variety of tools. Based on your input, you just want to replace all `,` with `\n`. So the shortest to write (and probably the fastest) approach would be `tr`:

```
$ tr ',' '\n' < file
elephant
kangaroo
 snake
 zebra
baboon
parrot
 eagle
 owl
```

Although that leaves the extra spaces.

In `awk` (GNU `awk`), you could do:

```
$ awk '{gsub(", ","\n");}1' file
elephant
kangaroo
snake
zebra
baboon
parrot
eagle
owl
```

In GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/, /\n/g' file
elephant
kangaroo
snake
zebra
baboon
parrot
eagle
owl
```

In Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/, /\n/g' file
elephant
kangaroo
snake
zebra
baboon
parrot
eagle
owl
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you intent on finding an `awk` solution?  It's quite easy to do in `sed` for example:

```
$ cat foo
elephant
kangaroo, snake, zebra
baboon
parrot, eagle, owl
$ sed -e 's/, */\
/g' < foo
elephant
kangaroo
snake
zebra
baboon
parrot
eagle
owl
```

Answer (score 1):

Done by using python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=open('p.txt','r')
for i in k:
    print re.sub(",","\n",i).strip().replace(" ","")
```

output

```
elephant
kangaroo
snake
zebra
baboon
parrot
eagle
owl
```